# What types of data are safe to transform to text for displaying in CLI?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building an npm package that is used to draw tabular data, e.g.

```
╔══════╤═════╤══════╗
║ foo  │ bar │ baz  ║
╟──────┼─────┼──────╢
║ frob │ bar │ quuz ║
╚══════╧═════╧══════╝
```

I need to know which types of data are safe to convert to text.

Comment: I would say anything non-explicit?

Comment: You should avoid every [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) (aka non-printing character), ie in ASCII chars below 32

Comment: @AndreaGhidini Thats a good advise.